# Scroll text in a textblock from code behind

Tags: silverlight, scroll, textblock

i need to scroll the textblock text.   For example, the textblock contains 700 words. These words are populated to the textblock from code behind as it could be a different 700 words depending on some "stuff".  There is a textbox on this form as well.  The user types the words in the textblock into the textbox.  As they type i keep track of which word from the textblock they are on.  However, not all the words in the textblock will fit in the textblock viewing area, so i need to scroll the textblock from code behind.  How do i go about doing this.

I"m using silverlight 3.

Thanks
shannon

sorry.. i didn't realize i didn't ask the question on it's own thread.. I'll post again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll want to wrap your TextBlock in a ScrollViewer control.  At that point, you can set the vertical and horizontal offsets of the ScrollViewer in the code behind like this.  Note this assumes a ScrollViewer control named ScrollViewer1.

```
    Private Sub ScrollViewer1_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, By Val e as System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs)
        Me.ScrollViewer1.VerticalOffset = Me.ScrollViewer1.VerticalOffset + e.Delta
    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the response.. i'm using vb.net for the backend.. and i've tried to convert what you've given.. but getting an error.


Dim focusedElement As FrameworkElement

        focusedElement = TryCast(FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(), FrameworkElement)

        Dim focusedVisualTransform As GeneralTransform

        focusedVisualTransform = focusedElement.TransformToVisual(Me.ScrollViewer1)

the error is   on this last line.  object reference not set to an instance.  I tried creating a new instantce.. no luck.. hope you can continue to provide some help

Comment: i did name the scrollviewer to ScrollViewer1

Comment: My code is actually aimed at moving a scrollbar as you tab through elements within it.  You're getting the error because you dont' have a focused element.  See my edit to handle the MouseWheel event of ScrollViewer1, which should do what you want.  I also converted it to VB.

Comment: just realized that you were suggesting the focusedElement.. the scrollviewer and textblock.. would they be the focused element... if the textblock is getting populated and handled completely in code behind... the user never touches anything in that textblock.

Comment: Yeah, see my comments above.  Also, the code I gave in the edit might need to be modifed to check for a negative offset or an offset greater than allowed...

Comment: great.. thanks for the code... i think i have it working now..  your guidence pointed me in the right direction.. again many thanks